# How can I put regularly accessed data into a "quick access" area in a database

Tags: mysql, performance, data-structures, mariadb

Very soon I will be building a database structure that will contain 2 million rows. Generally there are no more than 200 rows queried per minute and of those 200 it'll be 10-20 of those rows that are being queried.

Given the size of the table, I'd like to "store" the queried row somewhere so that any other end users querying this row will be able to get the row data "quicker". I then want this row to be accessed via this for a while and then put back into the main table once it's no longer in use. I believe this will make access quicker and more efficient.

Using the below schema, I'll provide an example. In this case row 1 has been accessed from the application layer. The application layer queries the "accessed" table to see if the row is there. If it is, it uses this and updates the "accessed" table with any changed data. If it isn't, it is queried from the main large table and dropped into the "accessed" table until the cron runs (say 10 minutes later) when all "accessed" data is copied into the main table and deleted from the accessed table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d76f6/2

I'm trying to work out the following:

1) Will this show an increase in efficiency (I would imagine each query against "accessed" instead of the main will be significantly faster)?

2) What technology should be used for the "accessed" data storage? It's likely the main table will be stored in MariaDB/MySQL, however I'm happy to run it in flat files, sqlite, a different instance or keep it within the same instance... I'm open to suggestions that will make this more efficient, and in theory there's no reason the application layer couldn't act as an intermediary between any technologies

Comment: This question has made me smarter, thanks. Sounds like you are on the right track.

Comment: @Andrew - thanks! That's one of my favourite things about Stackoverflow. Even though it's not meant to be a "discussion" site, there are so many opinions and ways of looking at things I find myself constantly reading things that turn my way of thinking around! :D.

Comment: I actually do not think this is a good idea. RDBMS have their own caches, and I'd expect them to do this sort of work for you. Doing this will make the application code much more complex and will envolve more communication between the client and the server. I doubt this will give better results then server caching. I'd try to look into tuning the server cache... or not worry about this at all until a real problem arises.

Comment: Please put all relevant details in the question itself as to prevent people from having to click around, people from fully understanding the question if they're unable to do so, and having this question make less sense if SQLFiddle ever shuts down or just kills the link for whatever reason.

Comment: @Frazz - That's a fair point. I'm not aware of caching done - any recommendations on reading for a good RDBMS for this type of situation? Or specific reading on MariaDB/MySQL (my current planned technology)? Happy to go down this path if it's feasible

Comment: @Dukeling - I'm not really sure how else to convey the data I've provided via the SQLFiddle link; Besides the point, its not pertinent, it's simply an example to help visualize what I'm trying to convey. Feel free to edit and add it in if you think it will help!

Comment: Since you're thinking MySQL... then you can start with the official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Answer (score 3):

Premature optimization. Overcomplex design to start with. What you want to implement is a most frequently accessed cache system. However, the duty of a DMBS system is indeed to do these kind of system optimizations for you. There are already caches at disk level, file system level, and database level. What you are saying is that, even before having the system in place, you already know it is not going to perform as expected.

Maybe you know more than you state in your question, but on the face of it, optimizations should be done after, with suitable profiling.

Comment: I second this... implement the simple solution and worry about optimizing only after you realize you have a problem. The world is full of databases with millions of rows that work fine without this type of solution.

Comment: @koriander - thanks, that's an excellent point. You're completely right - I'm assuming the problem and looking for potential solution before it happens. I'm doing this because once the data is there I'm going to need to react quickly and have a planned path to go down. I do appreciate your point though and maybe I'll generate some junk data and test scripts to work on performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to cache data.

On mysql you can use memory tables. Memory tables are much more faster than innodb-myisam tables

You can use memory based key value storage systems like redis, memcached

On application layer you can cache your data to filesystem

Comment: Thanks @talhasch - those are some great specific tips! As a general rule of thumb, is filesystem stored data (e.g. flat files I assume you mean?) going to be quicker than storing in a memory table or normal InnoDB table? Memcached is a great idea too, I'll look into that.

Comment: I've been doing some reading on memory based tables. These seem great for read only access, however as I'll be doing updates to the data before pushing it back to the primary table, how can I protect this data?

Comment: store cache data to memory table for reading. update memory table and primary table together when required.